# Is there a way to stop the Share Dialog on Facebook from directing users to the apps that I share?

Tags: facebook-apps

My Share Dialog works well. But after user has pressed the Post to Facebook button. It directs user to a link. Probably the redirect_uri value.

The thing is the redirect_uri value cannot be left empty. I want the share dialog just disappears after posting. Is there a way to do this? I read through the Share Dialog documentation but cannot find a way to do this.

Comment: please post the code that you are using in the question

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution :)

Here is the code for my share button:
Javascript:

```
function visitPage(){

    testwindow = window.open("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=[myAppID]&display=popup&href=[linkA]&redirect_uri=[linkB]","html","width=200, height=100");
    testwindow.moveTo(0,0);
}
```

HTML button:

```
<button onclick="visitPage()">Share</button>
```

And I created an HTML that closes itself immediately like this:

```
<!doctype html><html><head><script>
  window.onload = function load() {
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
  };
</script></head><body></body></html>
```

name it selfClosing.html or something like that and then put it into link B. DONE! :)